# Issue configuring insecure registry access with kops

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, kops

I'm using kops v1.8.1 and Kubernetes v1.10.0 on AWS to build my infrastructure.

I created an external plain HTTP docker registry following the procedure in this link:
    https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-a-local-registry

I then created a cluster using kops and added the following lines in the cluster spec manifest:

```
docker: 
  insecureRegistry: <hostnameofregistry> 
  logDriver: ""
```

Cluster is created but when trying to docker push to the insecure registry, it fails

I was expecting to be able to push or pull images from insecure registry without having to add any configuration on the master or nodes

I also tried using hooks to give access to the insecure registry to the master and nodes (based on the following procedure https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry).

I added the following hook to the cluster spec manifest:

```
hooks:
  - execContainer:
  command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - echo 35.155.193.162 <hostnameofregistry> >> /rootfs/etc/hosts &&
      echo { '"insecure-registries":["<hostnameofregistry>:5000"] } >> /rootfs/etc/docker/daemon.json &&
      /usr/bin/systemctl daemon-reload &&
      /usr/bin/systemctl restart docker.service
  image: busybox
```

That hook does modify /etc/hosts and creates /etc/docker/daemon.json on the master and nodes but I still need to manually do the daemon reload and restart docker for the master and nodes to have access to the insecure registry.

I'm relatively new to Docker and Kubernetes in general so not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong.
Any help or comment would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regarding your local registry, probably you may have a problem in firewall when you create the registry on one AWS node and try to access it from other nodes, but you may have not opened the port on registry node to your network, this is may be the reason it fails.

In general, [Amazon Elastic Container Registry](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) would be a good solution for you. Your infrastructure already is on AWS, so the good way is to use the components of AWS instead of some strange hacks.

In case you are using [AWS ECR, you just need to add IAM role](http://docs.heptio.com/content/private-registries/pr-ecr.html) to your Kubernetes nodes to get access to the registry.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for the answer. i'm still new to AWS and what it has to offer. Using ECR is indeed much easier and it solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nick, can you please detail your answer. I am facing similar issue too. But i am not using AWS ECR, i would need to connect to my nexus private registry for the same. So what could be used to make my cluster nodes to access my docker private registry?

Comment: @Shruthi Bhaskar but it is not the same, and I advise to use the ECR because it is already integrated to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by just doing

1. "kops edit cluster": 
          docker: 
              insecureRegistry: 100.0.0.0/24 (very general rule, ips change after cluster update)
              logDriver: ""
2. "kops update cluster --yes"
3. "kops rolling-update cluster --yes"